# »Anerkennen«: Trennbares Verb im Hauptsatz ungetrennt verwenden?

Tags: grammaticality, style, literature

Über folgenden Satz in einem Werk über das Lesen von Literatur bin ich gestolpert:

> Mit ihrem Beifall anerkennen die Zuschauer im Theater, dass das, was sie soeben gesehen haben, in den Bereich der Fiktion gehört.<sup>1</sup>

Die Wortform *anerkennen* als 3. Pers. Pl. ist eigentlich [dem Nebensatz vorbehalten](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/anerkennen:V:haben), da es sich um ein [trennbares Verb](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Trennbare-0n.html) (mit Betonung auf dem Präfix) handelt.
Im Hauptsatz müsste das Verb getrennt werden: »Sie erkennen an«.
Gängig wäre hier also:

> Mit ihrem Beifall erkennen die Zuschauer im Theater an, dass...

Ist der Satz im Buch korrekt?
Handelt es sich z. B. um eine Form der Betonung, die die Grammatik außer kraft setzt, oder gilt hier eine andere als die oben genannte Regel?

---

1) <sub>Eagleton, Terry (Übers. Holger Hanowell): Literatur lesen. Stuttgart, 2016, 15.</sub>

Comment: Nicht, daß ich nicht gerne mehr über das Thema wissen würde – in der anderen Frage wurde am Ende nur der Duden zitiert, und besonders schweizerisch scheint die Form auch nicht zu sein. (Der Übersetzer stammt, wenn ich richtig gegoogelt habe, aus Münster.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Verwendung von *anerkennen* als untrennbares Verb wie in

> Mit ihrem Beifall anerkennen die Zuschauer im Theater, dass das, was sie soeben gesehen haben, in den Bereich der Fiktion gehört.

kann man als eine durch häufigen Gebrauch zulässig gewordene Nebenvariante ansehen. Man spricht so zwar kaum, aber man liest es immer wieder.

Ich habe es bisher vor allem angetroffen in amtlichen Schreiben, juristischen Texten, honoratiorigen Versammlungsreden und sogar in Zeitungsartikeln - wenn auch nicht in solchen von höchster sprachlicher Qualität; eher in der typischen Vereinsberichterstattung, bei der sich auch aufmerksame Redakteure oft nicht so viel Mühe geben, denn dann müsste man eigentlich immer den ganzen Artikel neu schreiben.

Zur Entstehung folgende Spekulationen:

Die "richtige" (oder sagen wir: gewöhnliche) Verwendung mit abgetrennter Vorsilbe ist sehr umständlich und spröde. Das Verb *anerkennen* wird jedoch insbesondere in bürokratischen Zusammenhängen so oft verwendet, dass die Sprachverwender begonnen haben, es in dieser Form einzusetzen. Hier kommt hinzu, dass das Wort *anerkennen* in mündlicher, informeller Kommunikation eher selten verwendet wird, deutlich seltener jedenfalls als in schriftlichen Äußerungen.

Ich weiß es nicht, aber ich würde ein Glas guten Honigs darauf wetten, dass man die Verwendung von *anerkennen* als untrennbares Verb letztlich irgendwo in Verwaltungsakten des 19. Jahrhunderts zuerst auftreten wird finden.<sup>1</sup>

Ich anerkenne allerdings, dass dies eine reine Vermutung ist und dass ich mein Glas Honig auch verlieren könnte.

Ein Kontext, in dem *anerkennen* viel verwendet wird - oder jedenfalls wurde - ist die Welt der Schule: Wir haben früher oft eine "Anerkennung" bekommen; das war am Ende des Schuljahres eine Urkunde für gute Noten (ergänzend zum Zeugnis). Hier ist aus dem abstrakten Begriff für den Akt (der eigentlich durch das Verb *anerkennen* bezeichnet wird) ein Begriff für einen praktisch greifbaren Gegenstand geworden, nämlich die *Anerkennung* in Form der papierenen Urkunde. Vielleicht spielen solche Erfahrungen auch eine Rolle, wenn Leute sich scheuen, das Wort nach herkömmlichen Satzbauregeln auseinanderzuschneiden.

Gutes und schönes Deutsch ist es trotzdem oft nicht. Weder als *ich erkenne an* noch als *ich anerkenne*. Besser man ausweicht auf andere Verben:

> Mit ihrem Beifall bestätigen die Zuschauer im Theater, dass das, was sie soeben gesehen haben, in den Bereich der Fiktion gehört.<sup>2</sup>

Anderes Beispiel:

> Ich teile nicht deine Missachtung der Arbeit der Bienen, aber ich anerkenne deine Sorge um die Zähne der Menschen.<sup>3</sup>
>
> Ich teile nicht deine Missachtung der Arbeit der Bienen, aber ich erkenne deine Sorge um die Zähne der Menschen an.

Hier könnte man sagen (und dies mit ästhetischem Gewinn):

> Ich teile nicht deine Missachtung der Arbeit der Bienen, aber ich schätze deine Sorge um die Zähne der Menschen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Auch dies übrigens eine seltene, aber (jedenfalls regional) existierende syntaktische Nebenvariante. Standard wäre *auftreten finden wird*.

<sup>2</sup> Wer bei diesem Satz zusammenzuckt, weil die Zuschauer eigentlich nicht durch den Beifall *bestätigen*, dass das Gesehene Fiktion ist, sondern allenfalls, dass sie *erkannt haben bzw. sich der Meinung anschließen*, der müsste allerdings auch beim Originalsatz mit *anerkennen* zusammenzucken. Der Satz ist einfach an sich schon ein bisschen krude. Sauber gedacht und formuliert müsste er wohl heißen: *Mit ihrem Beifall zeigen die Zuschauer im Theater, dass sie das, was sie soeben gesehen haben, als Fiktion erkannt haben.*

<sup>3</sup> Aus einem Dialog zwischen einem Naturkostfreund und einem Zahnarzt. Aufgeschnappt 2019.

Comment: Auch wenn ich es gewinnen könnte würde ich nie um ein Glas Honig wetten.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Aus Angst vor Verlust? Oder weil du keinen Honig magst?

Comment: Ich mag keinen Honig und das Zeug ist schlecht für die Zähne. Bin immerhin Zahnarzt. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Ach ja, ich vergaß. - Aber wenn es schlecht für die Zähne ist, ist es doch gut für den Zahnarzt...

Comment: Ich habe den hippokratischen Eid geleistet! Wir wollen Schaden vom Patienten abwenden, und ihn nicht heraufbeschwören damit wir ihn kostenpflichtig beseitigen können.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis   Ich teile nicht deine Missachtung der Arbeit der Bienen, aber ich anerkenne deine Sorge um die Zähne der Menschen.

Comment: Wir brauchen Bienen. Aber nicht um ihren Honig. <g>