# áuferlegen oder auferlégen

Tags: difference, style, stress

Wörterbuchartikeln entnahm ich, dass dieses Verb getrennt wie ungetrennt Verwendung findet. In einem Buch habe ich folgende Erklärung gefunden, die ich allerdings nicht 100% verstehe:

> Um eine Passage besonders hervorzuheben, konjugiert man auch das
>   ungetrennte Verb: Man auferlegte dem Mädchen kaum erfüllbare
>   Pflichten.

Was ändert die Verwendung der ungetrennten Variante an der Aussage? Welchen stilistischen Klang bekommt sie somit?

NS: auf der Antwortsuche ist mir aufgefallen, dass dies auch einige andere trennbare Zeitwörter wie "**an**erkennen" betrifft, und dass es im 19. Jh. akzeptabler gewesen zu sein scheint.

Comment: Der Titel Deiner Frage ist irreführend: Beide Silben sind betont, ich erkenne keine zwei verschiedenen Arten der Aussprache.

Comment: @CarstenS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s29hNsIHV3c&t=21s Wie ist denn hier deiner Meinung nach *anerkennt* betont?

Comment: @DavidVogt, ich gebe zu, dass da eine starke Betonung auf „kennt“ liegt. Der (Schweizer!) Sprecher hat aber auch in „Börsenäquivalenz“ eine mir fremde Melodie mit starker Betonung auf dem Wortende.

Comment: Die Sprecherin im Beitrag hat bei flüssigerer Aussprache aber auch eine Betonung von „anerkennen“ (dem Infinitiv) auf „kennen“. Interessant.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, was unter getrennter Verwendung im Sinne des Wörterbuches zu verstehen ist. Aber je nach grammatikalischer Verwedung wird das Wort getrennt. "Das Mädchen bekam Pflichten **auferlegt**." und "Der Hausherr **erlegte** dem Mädchen Plichten **auf**".

Und ja, "Der Hausherr **auferlegte** dem Mädchen Pflichten" klingt altmodisch. Betont aber das Auferlegen und nicht die Pflichten.

Betont wird immer die erste Silbe.

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auferlegen

Hilft das weiter?

Comment: Danke für Deinen Beitrag! Bist du Dir ganz sicher, dass das Verb auch in der altmodischen Variante auch auf die erste Silbe benont wird? 
https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53279/9739

Comment: Ja, "auferlegen" wird immer auf der ersten Silbe betont. Auf__er__legt und aufer_legt__ klingt in meinen Ohren seltsam - aber da mag es regionale Unterschiede geben. Jedenfalls steht im Duden, dass die erste Silbe betont wird - und der hat per Definiton recht ;)

Comment: -1: Diese Antwort ist doppelt falsch: Einerseits wird sowohl die trennbare als auch die untrennbare Form im gegenwärtigen Deutsch verwendet – es kann also nicht die Rede davon sein, die eine wäre «altmodisch» und die andere nicht –, und andererseits liegt die Betonung bei der untrennbaren Form auf dem Wortstamm – egal was der Duden sagt.

Comment: Einverstanden, es mag sein, dass manche Leute die untrennbare Form als altmödisch empfinden. Diese Empfindung widerspiegelt allerdings eine Unkenntnis der Variationsbreite des gegenwärtigen Deutschs.

Answer (score 2):

Zu ähnlichem *anerkennen* siehe diese zwei Fragen: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/warum-wird-anerkennen-teils-als-untrennbar-betrachtet) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50521/anerkennen-trennbares-verb-im-hauptsatz-ungetrennt-verwenden?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Schon die Formulierung *konjugiert* aus dem nicht genannten Buch ist absurd. Hier geht es nicht um Konjugation – die Abwandlung eines Verbs nach grammatischen Merkmalen, also etwa *erlege, erlegst, erlegt* — sondern darum, was bei Voranstellung passiert, nämlich ob man das Verb wie ein trennbares behandelt oder nicht.

Ein stilistischer Unterschied ist zunächst einmal nicht gegeben, da die Verwendung einer der beiden Formen keine bewußte Wahl darstellt: Die meisten Sprechern verwenden *er erkannte an, er erlegte auf*, eine Minderheit *er anerkannte, auferlegte*. Nachgeordnet ergibt sich als stilistischer Effekt allenfalls, daß die Mehrheit die Minderheitenvariante merkwürdig findet.

Für die Betonung sollte gelten: Diejenigen Sprecher, die das Verb ungetrennt voranstellen, betonen den Stamm, also *auferlEgt*; sonst wird das Präfix betont, also *AUferlegt*. Für *anerkEnnt* Tonbelege [hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s29hNsIHV3c&t=21s) und [hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s29hNsIHV3c&t=1m2s).

Comment: Deklination ist enger in seiner Bedeutung als Konjugation im Sinne des Autors. Finde ich jetzt nicht erwähnenswert.

Answer (score 1):

(Wenn es nur um die stilistische Beurteilung geht, dannn gleich ans Ende springen.)

Es geht um die Trennbarkeit von Verben. Man unterscheidet

> **Präfixverben** = nicht trennbar, und
>
> **Partikelverben** = trennbar.

Die Präfixe der **Präfixverben** sind eine überschaubare Menge an 'Vorsilben', die in allen Formen mit dem Verbstamm verbunden bleiben. Es handelt sich um die Silben:

- be- : bekommen, bezahlen
- ent-: entstehen, entkommen
- emp-: empfehlen, empfangen (als Variante von 'ent' vor 'f')
- er-: erwarten, erzählen
- ge-: gehören, gefallen
- ver-: sich verlaufen, verspielen
- zer-: zerbrechen, zerreißen
- miss-: missdeuten, misslingen, missraten

und das veraltete

- ob-: jm obliegen (= die Verpflichtung haben zu), obsiegen (als Sieger hervorgehen)

Hinzu kommen einige Präpositionen bzw. Adverbien, die ebenfalls fest mit dem Verstamm verbunden benutzt werden können:

- durch-: etw durchdenken, ein Land durchfahren
- hinter-: einen Brief an der Hotelrezeption hinterlegen, Steuern hinterziehen, jemanden hintergehen (= täuschen, betrügen)
- über-: übertreiben, jm Geld überweisen
- um-: ein Wort umschreiben (= seine ungefähre Bedeutung mit anderen Worten wiedergeben), sich mit zweifelhaften Leuten umgeben, ein Problem umgehen
- unter-: unterschreiben, Geld unterschlagen
- voll-: vollenden (= zum Abschluss bringen), eine (rechtliche) Handlung vollziehen
- wider: jemandem widersprechen, sich widersetzen
- wieder-: etwas wiederholen

Zu dieser zweiten Gruppe von Präfixen existieren - bis auf die Betonung - homonyme Partikeln, die trennbar sind.

Alle Präfixe sind regulär immer fest mit dem Verbstamm verbunden, von halb-scherzhaftem Gebrauch abgesehen wie in

> Bitte verstehe mich jetzt nicht miss.

Bei den **Partikelverben** ist dem Verbstamm im Infinitiv eine Partikel vorangestellt, die sich in bestimmten syntaktischen Kontexten vom Verb ablöst und z.B. im Verbzweitsatz den zweiten Teil der Satzklammer bildet:

> Moment, ich schreibe mir eben die Telefonnummer *auf*.

Als Partikeln treten Präpositionen (*an*haben = ein Kleidungsstück tragen), Adverbien (sein Geld *zurück*haben wollen), Adjektive (am Nachmittag *frei*haben) und Nomina (an etw *teil*haben) auf. Die Liste möglicher Partikeln ist nicht abgeschlossen, zum Beispiel gibt es im Bereich der fremdsprachigen Partikeln Neuzugänge wie 'downloaden' mit vorerst unklarem Status (*downgeloadet* oder *gedownloadet*). Es werden ständig neue Kombinationen von Verben aus Partikel+Verb geschaffen, auch situationell (Er hat versucht, mich *anzuschleimen* = Neukombination aus *schleimen* = Sympathie heucheln + *an-* wie bei *sich anbiedern*, *jn anbaggern*). Die Möglichkeiten sind da unerschöpflich.

Bei **Kombinationen von Verbpräfix + Verbpartikel** scheint die Situation uneinheitlich. Es gibt sie als

> Partikel + Präfix: jn/etw einbeziehen, jn umerziehen

und (scheinbar) als

> Partikel + Partikel: sich voranmelden, ein Stück uraufführen

und (scheinbar) auch als

> Präfix + Partikel: Geld vereinnahmen (bürokratendeutsch für 'einnehmen', 'kassieren'), etw beabsichtigen (vorhaben), jn bevormunden, etw beanstanden

ja (scheinbar) sogar als

> Präfix + Präfix: jn missverstehen, jn verbeamten (ihm den Beamtenstatus zuerkennen)

Ohne dem hier weiter nachgehen zu wollen, sei dahingestellt, ob die scheinbaren Kombinationen sich nicht besser als Konversionen (Überführungen) von Wörtern aus anderen Wortarten in Verben erklären lassen als durch doppelte "Be-Vorsilbung" eines Verbstamms:

- uraufführen < Uraufführung
- vereinnahmen < Einnahme
- beabsichtigen < Absicht

und so weiter.

Die übergroße Mehrzahl der Doppel-Vorsilben-Verben sind nach dem Muster Partikel+Präfix+Verbstamm gebildet, und so verhält es sich auch bei 'jm etw auferlegen'.

Hinsichtlich der Trennbarkeit verhält sich die letztgenannte Gruppe großenteils wie einfache trennbare Partikelverben:

> Infinitiv: Du kannst die Jacke anbehalten.
>
> Präsens / Präteritum: Ich behalte / behielt die Jacke an.
>
> Imperativ: Behalte die Jacke ruhig an.

Auch der *Infinitiv mit zu* gliedert das -zu- wie bei einem Partikelverb hinter der Partikel ein:

> Infinitiv + zu: Man forderte mich auf, die Jacke anzubehalten.

Das Partizip Perfekt wird jedoch anders als bei einfachen Partikelverben ohne '-ge-' gebildet:

> Ich habe / hatte die Jacke anbehalten.

Hier ist die Partizip-Bildungsregel des Präfixverbs (Inf. *behalten* > Partizip 2 *behalten*) stärker als die Partizip-Bildungsregel eines Partikelverbs (*anhalten* > Partizip 2 *angehalten*: Der Polizist hatte mich angehalten).

Übertragen auf 'auferlegen' ergibt das:

> Inifnitv: Man wollte ihr weitere Pflichten auferlegen.
>
> Präsens: Man erlegte ihr kaum erfüllbare Pflichten auf.
>
> Imperativ: Erlege ihr das ruhig als zusätzliche Pflicht auf.
>
> Perf./Plqpf.: Man hat/hatte ihr zu viele Pflichten auferlegt.
>
> Passiv: Ihr wurden/waren zu viele Pflichten auferlegt.
>
> Infinitiv + zu: Ihr weitere Pflichten aufzuerlegen erschien ihm statthaft.

Bei einigen der nach diesem Muster gebildeten Verben wird manchmal das Verb wie 'doppelt untrennbar' behandelt. Dies mag dadurch begünstigt sein, dass weitere Verben eine ähnliche Struktur bei allerdings anderen Betonungsverhältnissen zeigen:

> Ableitung von Nomen: Er verfrühstückt das geerbte Vermögen.
>
> 'Doppel-Präfix': Wir verbeamten alle zügig, denn wir brauchen weitere Richter.

Zu den gelegentlich untrennbar auftretenden Verben gehören *anerkennen*, *aberkennen*, *zuerkennen*, *anberaumen*, *anempfehlen*, *anvertrauen*, *einverleiben*, *unterordnen*, *vorenthalten* und, wie ich lese, auch *auferlegen* - mir selbst ist diese stilistische Variante nicht geläufig, auch bei den anderen Verben nicht. Die weitaus überwiegende Zahl dieser Art von Verben tritt regelhaft trennbar auf.

Meine persönliche Einschätzung ist: Die untrennbaren Varianten werden entweder als **stilistisch intendiert** (so von mir, ich halte sie für mehr oder weniger snobistisch, **unkonventionell** bzw. effekthascherisch) oder **falsch** (bei Unkenntnis) oder unter '**Regionalismusverdacht**' (in der Schweiz gibt es auf diesem Gebiet einige Merkwürdigkeiten) oder Ähnlichem verbucht, oder sie sind einem **veraltet**en Sprachstand zuzuordnen. Auch haben sie für mich etwas von '**Bürokratendeutsch**', weil solche Verb-Ungetüme mit mehreren zumal abstrakten Vorsilben sich oft in juristischen oder administrativen Texten finden.

Das Buchzitat halte ich für sprachlich verquer und nicht gut verständlich: Weder kann man mit solchen Eigenwilligkeiten wie *man auferlegte dem Mädchen* "eine Passage hervor[zu]heben", noch passt "das ungetrennte Verb" mit "konjugieren" recht zusammen; gemeint ist wahrscheinlich "das Verb ungetrennt benutzen". Richtig ist: Der Beispielssatz mit dem ungetrennten *auferlegte* fällt auf, manchen wird dieser Satz stören.

Comment: "*sei dahingestellt, ob die scheinbaren Kombinationen sich nicht besser als Konversionen (Überführungen) von Wörtern aus anderen Wortarten in Verben erklären lassen*". Das ist schon wichtig, denn "Strafe auferlegen sollte" eigentlich *bestrafen* lauten. Der semantische Unterschied ist verschwindend gering. *Steuer hinterziehen* oder *jmd. etwas vorenthalten* sind aus etymologischer Sicht evtl. eher Verballhornungen; Vgl. etwa AHD *foa* "klein, arm". Sowie den Vgl. von En *try, trial* zu *zerren, ziehen, zeihen*, bzw. De. "Nachforderung" gegen "Hinterziehung".

Answer (score 1):

Vermutlich handelt es sich um eine regionale Unterscheidung. In der Schweiz und vielleicht auch in Österreich (vgl. den Hinweis bei [Duden | obsiegen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/obsiegen)) wird die untrennbare Variante bevorzugt, in Deutschland (im Norden?) hingegen die trennbare. Wenn es sich wirklich so verhält, dann könnte man wohl von einem eigentlichen [Teutonismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesdeutsches_Hochdeutsch) sprechen. Für mehr Information und weiterführende Literatur vgl. insb. den Artikel [Trennbare und untrennbare Verben](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Trennbare_und_untrennbare_Verben) in der [Variantengrammatik des Standarddeutschen](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Start).

Ein stilistischer Effekt ergibt sich somit nicht, abgesehen davon, dass in der jeweils anderen Region die dort nicht übliche Verwendung befremdet – was selbstverständlich völlig gegenseitig ist.

Der Eindruck, im 19. Jahrhundert sei die untrennbare Form häufiger gewesen, dürfte sich wohl aus der regionalen Verteilung herleiten (und nicht umgekehrt). Schliesslich war im 19. Jahrhundert die Vorherrschaft des nördlichen Deutsch noch nicht so erdrückend wie heute. Es war im Süden durchaus üblich, die typischen Ausdrücke des eigenen Hochdeutschs zu verwenden.

Wie bereits gesagt worden ist: Bei untrennbarer Verwendung wird der Stamm betont, bei trennbarer Verwendung hingegen die trennbare Partikel.

- ich auferLEGe – ich erlege AUF
- zu auferLEGen – AUFzuerlegen
- sie auferLEGt – sie erlegt AUF
- ich habe auferLEGt – ich habe AUFerlegt
- ich will auferLEGen – ich will AUFerlegen

Dasselbe Phänomen zeigt sich auch bei weniger unüblichen Verben, etwa bei [anerkennen](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Anerkennen), [übersiedeln](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/%C3%9Cbersiedeln_(Trennbarkeit)) oder [widerspiegeln](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Widerspiegeln). Die beiden letzteren weisen ferner darauf hin, dass es sich durchaus nicht auf «Doppel-Vorsilben-Verben» beschränkt.

Comment: Das mit widerspiegeln war besonders interessant, danke! Eine Deutschlehrerin hat es mal so verwendet, und da kam ich zum falschen Schluss, dass sie einen Fehler macht.

Answer (score 0):

Genauso wie "Pause machen" mit wiederholter zweifacher Abstufung. Eine vierfältige Abstufung mag hier und da kontrastieren, ist aber nicht lexikalisch und abhängig vom Versfuß.

Mangelnd der 'A-tem-technik und Sprech-Übbung wegen mag die Betonung vorn' am stärks'n sei'n, also *Au-verlegen*, was aber sinnentstellend wäre und deshalb entweder *aufer-* zu einer Mora zusammengefasst wird, oder eine kleine Pause einfügt bzw. den gutteralen Verschlusslaut im Ansatz zu *e* stärker betont werden muss, was dann wahlweise wie eine Verlängerung der ersten oder zweiten Silbe klingen mag. Je nach Dialekt wird *er-* durch Lenition (oder Syllibifikation) oft zu *a'*, ebenso wie der Ablaut *-en* klitisch mit dem approximierten Coda verschmilzt, *auf'alegn*, so dass eine vereinfachte dreisilbige Form mit der Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe entsteht. Equivalent: *Anerkennen* > *Anna kenn'*. Wahlweise kann das *r* auch schön lang getrellert werden um die Spannung auf das Thema zu erhöhen. Das gilt für den Berlin-Brandenburgischen Dialekt, variiert aber natürlich.

Hochsprachlich ist die Erklärung einfacher: Im Gegensatz zum Adjektiv "unterlegen" wird der Verbkern ***le-g-*** betont. Sollte zumindest. Das dem nicht so sein soll i.S.d. anderen Antworten, überrascht mich. Eventuell wird die Unterscheidung nicht getroffen, weil Partizipien weder reine Adjektive noch Verben sind. ...