# Trennbarkeit von »geringschätzen«

Tags: verb-usage, separable-verb

Ich habe bisweilen Probleme mit Worten wie *geringschätzen.* Ich würde immer schreiben/sagen:

> Ich **schätze** dieses und jenes **gering**.
>   Meine Eltern **schätzten** dieses und jenes **gering**.

Heutzutage treffe ich aber auch häufig auf Folgendes:

> Ich **geringschätze** dieses und jenes.
>   Meine Eltern **geringschätzten** dieses und jenes.

Aus meiner Sicht kann das nicht korrekt sein. Es sieht fast aus wie ein Anglizismus und wirkt auf mich, als würde man Mark Twain klein beigeben¹.

Was passiert hier? Gibt es einen Grund, das eine oder andere als richtig anzusehen?

---

<sup>¹ Übrigens voll der Lacher: *klein beigeben.* Also: »Ich **gebe** ihm **klein bei**« oder »Ich **klein beigebe** ihm« oder gar »Ich **beigebe** ihm **klein**«?</sup>

Comment: Wieso Anglizismus? Schwankungen zwischen Trennbarkeit und Untrennbarkeit sind bekannt (z.B. bei *anerkennen, auferlegen*). Bei *geringschätzen* mir allerdings nicht (und der Duden empfiehlt *gering schätzen*, was Untrennbarkeit ausschließt).

Comment: Anglizismus wegen (z.B.) "to download" gegenüber "Ich **lade** dieses und jenes **herunter**."

Comment: Wo ist noch mal das englische Wort hier, das analog zu *downlod* wäre? Auch ich sehe keinen Anglizismus, sondern was David eben schrieb.

Comment: Die Trennbarkeit bei Verben hat an sich nichts mit Anglizismen zu tun.

Comment: Die Nichttrennung von Verben u.U. schon, weil im Englischen zumeist keine Trennung vorliegt (was Twain ja gerade betont). Wenn der Sprachgebrauch in Deutschland zunehmend vom Englischen gefärbt ist, kann das schon auch einen Einfluss auf das Trennen zusammengesetzter Verben entfalten. Sichtbar z.B. wenn man im Alltag bisweilen schwankt zwischen "ich lade das mal down" und "ich downloade das mal" vis-a-vis "ich schätze das gering" und "ich geringschätze das".

Comment: „Die Nichttrennung von Verben u.U. schon, weil im Englischen zumeist keine Trennung vorliegt” klar, wenn die „u.U” bedeutet eben englische Worte, was eine Platitüde ist. Und  mit *gernigschätzen* unzusammenhängend ist.

Comment: @c.p. dein Kommentar ist übrigens mit der ursprünglichen Frage auch "unzusammenhängend". Nur mal so. Aber schwamm drüber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zwischen *verkaufen* (stammbetont) und *einkaufen* (Betonung auf der Partikel) gibt es einen grammatischen Unterschied:

> Er **verkauft** auf dem Markt. Auf dem Markt wird **verkauft**.
>   Sie **kauft** auf dem Markt **ein**. Auf dem Markt wird **eingekauft**.

Gewöhnlich bezeichnet man das Verb *verkaufen* als **untrennbar**: das Verb wird als Einheit vorangestellt, im Partizip II tritt kein *ge-* auf. Dagegen bezeichnet man *einkaufen* als **trennbar**: bei Voranstellung bleibt das *ein-* am Ende, beim Partizip II tritt das *ge-* vor den Stamm *kauf-*. (Etwas fachsprachlicher sind die Bezeichnungen **Präfixverb** und **Partikelverb**.)

Besonders populär sind Beispiele, bei denen Homographie vorliegt:

> wenn du wieder Passanten **umfährst**
>   1. Du **fährst** wieder Passanten **um**.
>   2. Du **umfährst** wieder Passanten.

Im Deutschen sind alle komplexen Verben in dieser Hinsicht bestimmt: Sie werden entweder als trennbar oder untrennbar behandelt. Diese Kategorisierung ist Teil des Sprachsystems des Deutschen und ihm nicht durch eine Fremdsprache aufgezwungen; die untrennbaren Präfixverben gab es schon im Althochdeutschen, z.B. *bigrifân* [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=begreifen).

Wie bei allen Unterscheidungen, die eine Sprache macht, gibt es bei einzelnen Wörtern Schwankungen im Gebrauch; siehe z.B. diese Fragen zu *auferlegen* und *anerkennen*:

- [áuferlegen oder auferlégen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53271/%c3%a1uferlegen-oder-auferl%c3%a9gen)
- [Warum wird „anerkennen“ teils als untrennbar betrachtet?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/warum-wird-anerkennen-teils-als-untrennbar-betrachtet)
- [»Anerkennen«: Trennbares Verb im Hauptsatz ungetrennt verwenden?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50521/anerkennen-trennbares-verb-im-hauptsatz-ungetrennt-verwenden?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Ich selber kenne *geringschätzen* ausschließlich als trennbares bzw. Partikelverb. Einen Einzelbeleg für den Gebrauch als untrennbares bzw. Präfixverb habe ich in einem Kommentar gefunden:

> Ich geringschätze tatsächlich die Denkfaulheit vieler Menschen. […] Aber ich geringschätze nicht andere Meinungen […] [republik.ch](https://www.republik.ch/dialog?t=article&id=882a24a2-fa45-4681-88a8-8cd12ae458e4&focus=ad5341de-7fdc-42ba-b3e2-36e7d64dd624)

Dieser Beleg genügt mir nicht, um den Gebrauch von *geringschätzen* als untrennbares Verb für möglich zu halten; da bräuchte es schon mehr. Ein weiteres Indiz, das gegen die Untrennbarkeit spricht, ist die Tatsache, daß der Duden die Schreibung *gering schätzen* [empfiehlt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gering_schaetzen). Die Getrenntschreibung ist aber mit der Verwendung als Präfixverb nicht kompatibel.

Die Vorstellung, es läge Beeinflussung durch das Englische vor, halte ich für falsch. Zwar ist es so, daß englische Begriffe wie *downloaden* im Prozeß der Eindeutschung Schwankungen zwischen Trenn- und Untrennbarkeit aufweisen; aber das liegt schlicht und ergreifend daran, daß die Sprecher sich erst entscheiden müssen, wie sie das fremde Wort behandeln wollen. (Ganz parallel dazu wären Schwankungen des Genus wie bei *die* oder *das E-Mail*.) Wie gesagt muß jedes komplexe Verb so kategorisiert werden, und die untrennbaren Verben sind keine Einschleppung aus dem Englischen, sondern waren schon immer Teil des Deutschen.

Comment: Super Antwort! Danke! Dennoch glaube ich, dass hier auch eine Beeinflussung aus dem Englischen vorliegen kann. Zwar geht es hier - das stimmt - um eine Entscheidung des Sprechenden, wie sie/er ein Wort wie "downloaden" eindeutschen möchte, doch je mehr Sprechende sich gegen eine Trennung entscheiden, desto häufiger hört man (und gewöhnt sich an) nicht getrennte composita.

Comment: Ich schätze das wert :-) Ernsthaft, mit der Antwort wurde mir auch was klarer. Danke.